# Can I avoid re-rendering parent route handler component when the route changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm noobies in react / redux and I'm looking to create modal view following this 3 rules :

- who is url dependant
- who is generic
- who is optimized

Cause of the url dependancy it's not optimized, it's rerender the parent.

**Example**: I have a view namespaces view at '/namespaces' who print all namespaces and when I open '/namespaces/edit' who open the modal view the namespaces is rerender. How to not rerender the namespaces list ?

Below the **Router**

```
<Route path="namespaces" component={NamespaceList}>
   <Route path="edit" component={NamespaceEdit}/>
   <Route path="create" component={NamespaceCreate}/>
</Route>
```

**NamespacesList** component

```
function NamespacesList({ push, children }) {
  console.log("rendered !")
  return (
    <div>
      NamespacesList
      <p>
        <Link to="/namespaces/create">Create</Link>
        <br />
        <Link to="/namespaces/edit">Edit</Link>
      </p>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

**NamespacesCreate** component (printed inside of the modal)

```
const NamespacesCreate = function() {
  return (
    <Modal>
      NamespacesCreate
      <p>
        <Link to="/namespaces">Back to namespaces list ?</Link>
      </p>
    </Modal>
  )
}
```

Use case :
I'm on the `/templates/create` (namespacelist is drawing in the back of the modal, in the console `rendered !` is printed then when I click to link to comeback to the parent url `/templates`, `rendered !` is printed again.

So there is a way to "optimize" it and not rerender the namespaceList or I need to choose between, or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don’t worry about how many times the component’s `render()` method is called. Rendering is *very* cheap in React, and if the content has not changed, it will not actually touch the DOM.

You should only start worrying about `render()` method calls when you start to experience real performance problems in your app which is very unlikely for one-off things like navigations. For example, you might want to optimize animations or form components that have ton of inputs.

**If and when** you have this problem (not earlier!), you can check out React guides to [Advanced Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html) optimizations, [measuring wasted renders with `ReactPerf`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html#perf.printwastedmeasurements), and [learn about common performance anti-patterns](https://medium.com/@esamatti/react-js-pure-render-performance-anti-pattern-fb88c101332f#.8kmy2fjai).

Don’t let this complicate your code for no reason though. Only optimize when you have a real problem, and no sooner. React is very fast for most users’ needs out of the box, and `render()` method being called often is perfectly fine.

Comment: I know rendering is very cheap in React but is there any solution to avoid re-rendering? My parent component gets re-rendered again which shows a flicker on the screen and i want to avoid that re-rendering so no flicker occurs. @Dan Abramov

Comment: What if in 'NamespacesList' component, we load the list from a server via api call? Will that api be called?